# Prompt user to key in 20 integers from 0 to 99. From that data display the prime numbers

Tags: c++

Prime number part code is not working, it says i cant compare pointer and interger. I not sure what to do.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int input[20] , i;

for (int i = 0; i < 20 ; i++)
{
    cout << " Enter 20 interger numbers from 0 to 99 "<< endl;
    cin  >> input[i];
}

for (i=2; i<20 ; i++) // edited as per the comments below
{
    if(input==i) // there is error here saying cant compare like this
    {
        cout << input << endl ;
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please properly format code

Comment: Change `for (i=2; i<input ; i++)` to something like `for (i=2; i<20; i++)`.  As per your code, you are comparing input (pointer to first element of the array) to an `int (i)`.  Hence, the error.

Comment: don't live edit your code when someone tells you something wrong with it...SO isn't a live debugging session, and changing your code to correct mistakes pointed out by the answers makes the answers invalid. That's not fair to the answerer

Comment: owh im sorry.. im new here.. thanks for pointing it out...

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm for finding prime numbers is wrong. Try this one. This is working solution.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int input[20] , i,prime,t;
    cout << " Enter 20 interger numbers from 0 to 99 "<< endl; //
    for (int i = 0; i < 20 ; i++)
    {
        cout << " Enter a number"<< endl; //
        cin  >> input[i];
    }

    cout << " prime numbers are: "<< endl; //
    prime=1;
    for (i=0; i<20 ; i++)
    {
        for(t=2;t<input[i];t++)
        {
            if(input[i]%t==0){
                prime=0;
                break;

            }
        }

        if(prime==1 && input[i]!=0){
            cout << input[i] << endl;

        }
        prime=1;
     }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am afraid this code would not work for prime check. `prime = 1` must be initialized within the for loop. Check out my example.

Comment: yes thank you.. it works. just when 0 is entered it shows as prime number which is not. i guess a simple condition should fix tht right?

Comment: You must make sure after taking input that the integer is **positive** and only then progress to the prime checks. If not positive, immediately mark it as not prime.

Comment: This code will not work if you give an input like 2, 4, 6, 8. It will mark all as prime as the `prime` flag he is using is initialized outside.

Comment: @VaibhavBajaj. It is working for the input like 2,4,6,8.

Comment: Because i have initialize again as prime=1 at the end of main for loop

Comment: @dulajsanjaya I am sorry but I did not spot the `prime = 1` at the bottom earlier. Was it always there? If so, it would work fine. As an apology, take an upvote.

Comment: Yes. It was always there. I didn't edit the answer. Your algorithm is also okay. You have used break point. It is good to reduce the time complexity. thank you.

Comment: edited code for the input- "0"(as question asked to find prime numbers from 0 to 99)

Answer (score 0):

Your prime check is incorrect. The code:

```
for (i=2; i<input ; i++)
{
    if(input==i)
    {
        cout << input << endl ;
    }
}
```

does not serve any purpose. When you refer to `input` in `i < input`, you are actually referring to a pointer which points to the first element of the array. What you actually need to do is permute over all the elements of this array and check if they are prime or not. Something like what is shown below should work:

```
bool flag;
for (i=0; i<20 ; i++) //Go over all 20 elements in array
{
    flag = true;
    for(int j = 2;j < input[i];j++)
    {
        if(input[i] % j == 0)
        {
            flag=false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(prime==true)
        cout << input[i] << endl;
}
```

Here, if the number in `input[i]` is divided by any number from 2 to `input[i]` and gives the remainder 0 (checked by modulus - `%` - operator), it is not prime. 
 We initially consider it to be prime and set the `flag` to `true`. If we find out it is divisible by something other than 1 or itself, we set `flag` to `false` and the break statement breaks out of the inner for loop as no further checks are required.
Here, `input[i]` refers to the element with the `i`th index in the array with 0 indexing.

Comment: I will add code for that soon. Till then, search up the modulus operator.

Comment: Your welcome. Please next time, try to understand the concepts on your own and formulate your own code. Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. I got the full working code here. Just a quick question, it there anything else I need to change to make it better.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int i,t, max, min, x[20], even=0, odd=0, prime; 
cout << "Enter 20 integer numbers from 0 to 99: "<<endl;
for (i=1;i<=20;i++)
{
    cout << "Input " << i <<":";
    cin >> x[i];
}
min=x[0];
max=x[0];
for(int i=1;i<=20;i++)
{
    if(min>x[i])
    {
        min=x[i];
    }
    else if(max<x[i])
    {
        max = x[i];
    }

}
cout<<"Max is "<< max <<endl;
cout<<"Min is "<< min <<endl;

cout << "Prime numbers are: " << endl ; 
prime=1;
for (i=2; i<=20 ; i++)
{
    for(t=2;t<x[i];t++)
    {
        if(x[i]%t==0)
        {
            prime=0;
        }
    }

    if(prime==1)
    {
        cout << x[i] << endl;
    }
    prime=1;
}
return 0 ;   
}
```